# Google mock on gRPC

Tags: c++, grpc, googletest, googlemock

I want to test client and thus mocking server by gmock.
My proto is defined as

```
// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Streaming request and reply
  rpc StreamRequestAndReply (stream Request) returns (stream Reply) {}
}


message Request {
  int32 idx = 1;
  bool is_pause = 2; // control message
}

message Reply {
  string msg = 1;
  bool is_eof = 2;
}
```

And the correspinding function on server-side looks like

```
Status StreamRequestAndReply(ServerContext *context, ServerReaderWriter<Reply, Request> *stream) override {
  // do something
}
```

My question is: how to write my predefined Reply message via the mocked stub by gmock, for example I want to reply three valid message and then set is_eof in the fourth one?

My current thinking is using testing::Invoke, but haven't figured out how to capture the stream and call the Write function. Can someone give me some suggestions and hints?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous gRPC provides virtual functions for all interfaces, which could be mocked by `StubInterface`.

Asynchronous gRPC (i.e. `CompletionQueue`) doesn't provide such functionality, since it's just a thin wrapper around C implementation. In this case, better to set-up a local fake server, and unit test it in an integration-like way.